# How do I find the corresponding name with ID number in CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

(this is my first post on SO, so please let me know if this isn't proper formatting!)

I'm making a form that'll pull the name when given an ID number from a CSV file and have absolutely no idea where to start.

Example Data:

| ID Number | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |
| 2 | Jane Shmoe |
| 3 | Kane Foe |

So if I input the ID number "1", it'll output "Jane Doe"

Thanks

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, you will find the python community here is very active and helpful but we do ask that you at minimum make some effort at the code and show some code that doesnt work. Currently it seems like your just asking for someone to do your homework. Some suggestions, use the csv module in python and then make a dict of id and name and then look them up

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) from [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and create a dictionary of your data:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    data = {d['ID Number']: d['Name'] for d in list(reader)}

num = input('Input an ID Number: ')
print(data.get(num, 'Not found'))
```

Output:

```
Input an ID Number: 1
John Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this based on subsetting. Start by reading in the data as a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("<filename>.csv")
```

From here you want to query your name column by the id, so (as an example) if you want to find the name associated with ID = 1:

```
result = df[df["ID Number"] == 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load the csv into a dictionary, then repeatedly ask the user for input:

```
file = open("example.csv", "r")
d = {}
for line in file:
    split = line.strip().split(",")
    d[split[0]] = split[1]

while True:
    id = input("Please input an ID: ")
    print(d[id])
```

Output:

```
Please input an ID: 1
Jane Doe
Please input an ID: 3
Kane Foe
Please input an ID: 2
Jane Shmoe
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint on how you have to do it using panda:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

user=df[df['ID Number']==2].iloc[0]
print(user.to_dict())
```

In this example, we were looking for the users with id of 2. Then we choose the first item found.
The next step, we convert it to dictionary and print it.

You can use different function to read in Command line interface, such as input (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-input-in-python/).